# What does ADOM randomly generate?

Tags: adom

In Nethack, the world and your inventory are randomly generated at the start of the game. I just started playing ADOM, and I noticed that both times I came across the same village at the start of the game.

So now I'm curious - what does ADOM randomly generate, or what typo of things are fixed for every play through?

I read that dungeons and stats are randomly generated - but have not found any source one way or the other on anything else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easier to list the fixed elements than the randomly generated elements. Below is a list of all map layouts that are fixed. The presence of all dungeons not listed will be fixed, but their actual structure (as well as the structure of all levels not specified within a particular dungeon) will be randomly generated.

- The world map's basic structure
- The structure and primary denizens of all towns or "peaceful" areas, both in the world map and in the Caverns of Chaos.
- The Stone Circle, the Water Dragon's Lair, and the Quickling Tree are all single level dungeons that are fixed in design.
- The Pyramid, the Dwarven Graveyard, and the Bug Infested Ruins have all of their floors fixed.
- The last level of the Tomb of the High Kings, the Darkforge, the Rift, and that mysterious cave in the middle of the continent.
- The Temples are fixed - they always have the same structure, but they only take up half of the floor they are assigned to. The other half of the floor will remain randomly generated.
- The last 3 levels of the Caverns of Chaos are fixed in structure.
- The actual dungeon level they are found on varies, but the Big Room, the Animated Forest, the Eternal Guardian's room, the Casino, and the Bunny Floor all are fixed in structure.

In addition, you are guaranteed various items and events to occur - the availability of all quests, and all items that are associated with those quests, is fixed. All of the above fixed maps will always feature certain features that will always be the same, including treasure and monsters. However, in all scenarios there is still random generation going on, so you can end up with more than just the base layout.

Past that, several of the other dungeons will still have fixed encounters, usually in accordance with a quest. As well, certain dungeon elements (such as vaults) will have a fixed structure to them, but are randomly picked from various possible layouts.

You can read up more on these elements [at the ADOM Guidebook](http://www.adomgb.info/adomgb-toc.html), though keep in mind it's highly spoilery. Any area that *doesn't* contain a map is going to be randomly generated. All elements that are fixed will also be pointed out in the respective points that they can be found.

Answer (score 4):

The overworld map is fixed, and so are its major features (cities, dungeons, tile types, but not random encounters etc.). Most plot quests are also fixed.

Pretty much everything else is as random as you might expect from roguelikes. Most notable is the `I`nfinite dungeon for its endless supply of random levels (beware: going upstairs does *not* take you to the previous level, but to an entirely new one closer to the surface.)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! It caught me off guard when the world map appeared to be fixed - since I thought Roguelike games randomized everything (I'm fairly new to Roguelikes... which is clearly a crime against humanity)

Comment: @Wipqozn: even Nethack has fixed levels, although you're likely to die many times before seeing any of them, unlike in ADOM where you can see one at the start...